# Trying to increment data with function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to increment a data property with a function however the code is not allowing me to. I'm wondering what I am doing wrong here? The logic looks correct for the most part but I'm still new to Vue so I can't figure it out. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this item. I was also wondering if there was a way to make the code more elegant. Basically for each toggle I'd like the price to either increment or decrement, and the price will be the price that the customer may pay depending on what the customer has selected.

```html
    <div id="app">
                <button @click="toggle1">1</button>
                <button @click="toggle2">2</button>
                <button @click="toggle3">3</button>
                <button @click="toggle4">4</button>
                <button @click="toggle5">5</button>
                <button @click="toggle6">6</button>

                {{ price }}
            </div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script>
        let app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                oneActive: false,
                twoActive: false,
                threeActive: false,
                fourActive: false,
                fiveActive: false,
                sixActive: false,
                price: 0,
                oneprice: 20,
                twoprice: 50,
                threeprice: 30,
                fourprice: 40,
                fiveprice: 30,
                sixprice: 40
            },

            methods: {
                toggle1() {
                    if (this.oneActive = false){

                    this.price += this.oneprice;
                    this.oneActive = true;

                    }
                    else if (this.oneActive = true){

                        this.price -= this.oneprice
                        this.oneActive = false;
                    }
                },
            }

        });

        </script>
```

Comment: Your code uses `toggle2` and on, but they are not defined in the Vue instance. Is that it or you just didn't paste the code?

Comment: First mistake that jumps out is using `=` instead of `===` for the `if` checks. I suggest using an IDE and/or linter that will detect such mistakes.

Comment: I did try to use === as well but to no avail. I didn't post toggle2 but I haven't created it yet I just wanted to try toggle1 and see if it works first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more elegant way to write this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" @click="toggleItem(index)">
      {{ item.name }}
    </button>
    <p>{{ totalPrice }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { price: 20, name: 'item 1', isActive: false },
        { price: 40, name: 'item 2', isActive: false },
        { price: 60, name: 'item 3', isActive: false },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    totalPrice() {
      return this.items.filter(item => item.isActive).reduce((a, b) => a + b.price, 0);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggleItem(index) {
      this.items[index].isActive = !this.items[index].isActive;
    },
  },
};
```

The key insight is that you can call methods with arguments from your template.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try to digest it but I don't know how filter or reduce functions work yet and it is a little over my head. I know DRY is a thing but the way I've built it out makes more sense to me at the moment. Is it possible you can figure out why my code is not working as well? Once again thank you.

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) creates a new array with only the matching items (in this case only those with `isActive` set). [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) applies a function over an array to compute a single value (in this case we compute a sum). The result is that we sum over an array where `isActive` is set.